# Initializing "external" functions before they are created

Tags: rust, jit, unsafe

Basically I have a function called `gen_func()` which takes in a `&mut extern fn(i64) -> i64` then generates some code and places it in the reference.

The problem arises when I try to create an input to this function.

I don't know what the code to get such a function allocated would look like.

```
let func = [what goes here?];
gen_func(&mut func);
```

Edit:
As people in the comments pointed out this question is a lot more nuanced than I thought so here is some further information:

I have complete control over the `gen_func()` function. It uses a code generation library ([gnu lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)) to generate a function.

My goal is to have a function which can generate another function which can then be executed.

Comment: Are you in control of the signature of `get_func()`? Is it non-Rust code? How to do this without UB will depend on whether you can tweak the signature, at least on the Rust side.

Comment: This is a lot more nuanced than you might think. First of all, `fn` pointers are just pointers to the code of the function. A `&mut fn(i64) -> i64` actually just allows you to change the *pointer*, which doesn't seem to be what you want. However, this is a minor fix. The bigger issue is actually writing to the function. On virtually every modern system, executable pages will be guaranteed to be unwritable. You'll probably have to use a crate like [memmap2](https://docs.rs/memmap2/0.5.3/memmap2/) to make a writable and executable page, copy the function code over, and then execute it.

Comment: @Aplet123 I suspect this is actually FFI to some C library that does codegen or otherwise "discovers" function pointers (OpenGL comes to mind).

Comment: I am sorry I undersetimated the complexity of my questinon. I added some more information in an edit I hope it helps.

Comment: @slackers Changing the signature of the function to return a function pointer is probably the better approach, based on your edits. I've added this suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behavior to create a reference to a value that doesn't exist, so the only way you can accomplish this without undefined behavior given your current constraints is to initialize `func` to some other `extern fn(i64) -> i64` that already exists.

If you are able to change the signature of `gen_func` you could have it return the function pointer instead:

```
fn gen_func() -> extern fn(i64) -> i64 { todo!(); }
```

I suspect that `get_func` is itself an `extern` function implemented in C, which accepts an "out" pointer-to-function-pointer.  In that case, you can get around the issue by changing the Rust-side signature to either a raw pointer (`*mut extern fn(i64) -> i64`) or a safer type like [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html).

For example:

```
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

extern "C" {
    fn gen_func(fp: &mut MaybeUninit<extern fn(i64) -> i64>);
}
```

Now we can implement a safe interface without UB.  We create an uninitialized `MaybeUninit` and give a reference to `gen_func`, which populates the pointer.  Then we can assume it's initialized.

```
fn gen_func_wrapper() -> extern fn(i64) -> i64 {
    let mut func = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    unsafe {
        gen_func(&mut func);
        func.assume_init()
    }
}
```

Note that `MaybeUninit<T>` and `T` are guaranteed to have the same layout, so the non-Rust side would not see any difference here.